# CREATE DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction. Dynamic database creation using stored procedure + EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to create a database using a stored procedure as shown here:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_CreateDatabase]
    @dbName nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @createDbQuery nvarchar(max) = 'CREATE DATABASE '+ Quotename(@dbName);
    EXEC (@createDbQuery)
END
```

This stored procedure will be in the `Master` database.

When I execute this in Management Studio, it works as expected and the database is created.

C# code:

```
using (Data.MasterDB db = new Data.MasterDB())
{
     db.usp_CreateDatabase(databaseName);
}
```

`dbContext` has the connection string of the `Master` database.

But when I try to execute the same from my application using Entity Framework, it throws

> CREATE DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction.
>   Database 'TestDb' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly

Comment: Well, the error message says it all. EF creates a wrapping transaction around stored procedure calls as well, and maybe, there is something else going on inside the transaction, initiated by EF.
Can you maybe check with a profiler what statements are run exactly and where are the transaction boundaries?

Comment: @AkosNagy - there don't have to *be* any other statements. `begin transaction
create database ABC;
commit` triggers the same error. The only transaction that `create database` can be in is the autocommit transaction that SQL Server wraps around a statement that requires a transaction and that isn't already inside of one.

Comment: Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

Is your application creating a Transaction before executing the procedure? 
If so, that would cause this problem since the Procedure is also creating a transaction.

You will see this same behavior if you were to execute the procedure in management studio (or any IDE) with "Auto-Commit" turned off, or if you wrapped it in a transaction like so:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    EXECUTE dbo.usp_CreateDatabase TmpData
COMMIT;
```